# c++ Search Blocks Of Large Image For Sub Image

Tags: c++, search, matrix, block

Given that my large and sub image are 2D matrices, how would I be able search my large matrix block by block until my sub matrix is found. It's like OpenCV template matching but I'm not using that so this needs to be C++ purely. 
Something like this. Some sample code would be much appreciated.

```
SearchBlock(//parameters)
{
    Matrix Block;
    Block.Rows = //define block rows;
    Block.Cols = //define block cols;
    Block.data = new double[Block.Rows * Block.Cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < Block.Rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Block.Cols; j++)
    return Block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by iterating over the elements of the image matrix and checking if the neighbouring elements correspond to the elements of the subimage you are looking for.